# Editing the current User in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users can be edited from a normal resourceful URI like:

```
/users/1/edit
```

The issue is that in my application, the edit user page is the home page or root route.

```
# routes.rb

root :to => "users#edit"
```

So, I tried to set `@user` to the current user in the absence of `params[:id]`.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def edit
  @user = (params[:id]) ? User.find_by_id(params[:id]) : @current_user
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting the form to point properly.

```
# app/views/shared/_manage_users.rb

<%= form_tag follow_user_path, :id => 'update-following-form' %>
```

I'm getting:

```
No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"users"}
```

`follow` is a member route of the user resource and has a corresponding controller method. If I access the page via the URI at the top of this question, `/users/1/edit`, everything works fine and no error is thrown.

I'm not sure whether I'm going about this completely the wrong way or if I'm just not using the right form helper or something silly. **How can I fix this issue, or what steps can I follow to debug it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member route expects the member to be passed as an argument. You route is expecting a User, like so:

```
follow_user_path(@user)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your routes do this

```
resource :user
```

instead of

```
resources :users
```

now the id param is notin the url.  you just need to ensure the user is logged in

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to actually define follow_user in your routes.rb.

Example:

> post "user/follow" => "users#follow", :as => :follow_user